# Certificate Verify, "error:068000C7:asn1 encoding routines::unknown signature algorithm"

Tags: c++, openssl, x509, ecdsa, sha-3

I would like to create a certificate with ECC. I am using `ecdsa_with_SHA3-512` as signature algorithm.

I can succesfully sign the certificate as below.

```
auto message_digest = EVP_MD_fetch(nullptr,"SHA3-512", nullptr);
if (!message_digest) {
 ...
}

if(auto ssize = X509_sign(cert,pkey,message_digest)){
 ...
}
```

But I can`t verify the signature as below.

```
auto result = X509_verify(cert,pkey);
if (result <= 0) {
 printf("[verify is failed : %d]\n",result);
}

auto errCode = ERR_peek_last_error();
auto errBuf = new char[256];
ERR_error_string(errCode,errBuf);
std::cout << errBuf << "\n";
```

I get `[verify result : -1]` `error:068000C7:asn1 encoding routines::unknown signature algorithm` error message.

I am checking tbs signature and certificate signature objects, they are equal.

```
if(X509_ALGOR_cmp(signatureAlg, tbsSignature)) {
 ...
}
```

Below is tbs signature object fields.

```
tbs signature ln : ecdsa_with_SHA3-512
tbs signature sn : id-ecdsa-with-sha3-512
tbs signature nid : 1115
```

As I understand X509_verify() checks the signature algorithm nid from
`nid_triple sigoid_srt[]` array. And cant find `NID_ecdsa_with_SHA3_512` algorithm nid. Because of this, it gives unkown algorithm error.

I am new to cryptography and openssl, What I am missing.

Edit : This hash/signature algorithm combination is not
supported by any of the current releases by itself.

Comment: FWIW: Windows doesn't support SHA-3 yet, so a certificate with a SHA-3 based signature will not work there.  I don't think macOS/iOS do, either.  (Your problem may be related in that you're trying to be a bit too bleeding-edge, but I don't actually know.)

Comment: Then again, Windows crypto is not directly a frontrunner right? I mean it now has GCM, but *dang*, that took long.

Comment: I think this is not related to Windows. I am using openssl library api’s and its application on ubuntu terminal. Openssl library gives unknown algorithm error. 
@bartonjs

Comment: @selim I understand that. I’m just pointing out that SHA-3 certificates aren’t something that the world at large is ready for, so it /might/ not be something worth pursuing at this time. (And that, relatedly, it may be that not even OpenSSL is ready for them).

Comment: @bartonjs, Ohh I understood you wrong, thank you for answer.